Greykite - Model_template SILVERKITE - Trouble with holidays_to_model_separately
New to Python Machine Learning, it's kind of easy to implement an easy model using Greykite but when one wants to optimize it, things get more difficult.

First, there's no sales on sundays and the model seems not to like it. But it manages to produces great results. ('y_true contains 0. MedAPE is undefined.' is one of a long list of outputs)
What brings me here is that I would like the algorythm to use past sales for not working days in France : there's for example always a 0 value for Mai 01. When implemented, the forecast gives positives values (lower than the other day).
Example for May 1st

custom_silverkite = ModelComponentsParam(
     events = {
         "holiday_lookup_countries": ["France"],
         "holiday_pre_num_days": 0,
         "holiday_post_num_days": 0,
         "holidays_to_model_separately":  ["All Saints' Day",
          'Armistice Day',
          'Ascension Day',
          'Assumption Day',
          'Christmas Day',
          'Easter Monday',
          'Labor Day', #May the first
          'National Day',
          "New Year's Day",
          'Victory Day',
          'Whit Monday'
                                         ]
     },
     custom={"min_admissible_value":0}
)
A_Date=datetime.datetime(2024,1,31)
forecast_config = ForecastConfig(
    model_template = "SILVERKITE",
    forecast_horizon = 100,
    coverage = 0.9,
    metadata_param = MetadataParam(
      time_col = "Date",
      value_col = "nb",
      freq = "D",
      train_end_date=A_Date
   )
  ,model_components_param=custom_silverkite
)
forecaster = Forecaster()

silverkite = forecaster.run_forecast_config(
df = df,
config = forecast_config,
)

I've run into the greykite documentation and have looked for similar posts without sucess.
